# How do I attach several SMD LEDs to the same optic fiber?

Tags: fiber-optics

I've got a PCB with five SMD LEDs in two groups (group PSU: 2 LEDs; group BAT: 3 LEDs), of which no more than one LED in each group is switched on:

[image: LED layout]

Logic: `PSUGN nand PSURD` and `BATYW nand BATGN nand BATRD`.

So I've got the idea to attach the LEDs of each group to one single ø 3 mm PVC fiber optic cable, so that I'll only need two fibers instead of five. Additionally, there's another object just 10 mm above the PCB with the LEDs, so that I'll need a space-saving solution.

Now: Is there a possibility or maybe even a ready-to-use "bifurcation" for fiber optics, which allows me to attach several LEDs to one fiber?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Example: When PSURD emits red light, I'd like to see red light at the other end of fiber #1, and when PSUGN emits green light, then green light shall come out of the fibre.

Answer (score 2):

I would put a diffuser across the LED strip to "mix" the light and position the fiber to the diffuser. This will, however, considerably attenuate the brightness. You might be able to live with that.

If you can't live with that, the only other way I can think of that uses one fiber for multiple LED's is to use coupling optics (lenses or mirrors) to funnel the light into the core. This will have a better coupling coefficient but it's much more complicated.

As a compromise, independent fibers for each LED will retain most of the brightness and is easiest to implement. You can get an array of fibers bundled in one package.

Answer (score 0):

Use an RGB LED.  These position the emitters very close to one another, so you can mount the fiber directly above a single package and get 3 colors into the fiber.

Comment: The PCB is NOT self-made, but ready to use, so that I can't change the LEDs.